# Cakephp timeAgoInWords to stop at the first value

Tags: cakephp, time

I am using the timeAgoInWords function in cakephp and I would like to know if there is a way to stop at the first time value, here is what I mean.

I have this code so far...

```
echo $this->Time->timeAgoInWords($post['created'],array('accuracy'=>array('day'=>'day')));
```

And some of my posts have a date that says `5 days ago` while some others have `1 week, 5 days ago`

How can I get all instances to stop at the first value so that `1 week, 5 days ago` will just say `1 week ago`

Keeping in mind that later on that some 1 week item may say `1 month ago` instead of `1 month, 2 weeks, 7 days ago`

Comment: Have you thought about just using CakePHP's `niceShort()` instead?:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/time.html#CakeTime::niceShort

Comment: Well we really wanted the time ago format.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the accuracy of each possible states :
        `accuracy'=>array('day'=>'day','week'=>'week','month'=>'month','year'=>'year')`